# What is the impact of enabling/disabling ROW_MOVEMENT in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We are using oracle 10G and one of the table takes lot of time if we query/delete data. This table contains around 10 million records.

Recently we discovered that ROW_MOVEMENT is disabled on this table, we want to understand following:

1. What performance gain we can get if enable ROW_MOVEMENT ?
2. Are there any downsides of enabling ROW_MOVEMENT ?
3. What trigger's row movement ? How does oracle decides it needs to move ROWS ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Row movement is mainly [applied to partition tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54623). It allows rows to be moved across partitions. With row movement disabled, which is the default, you can't move a row with an update:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE part_table (ID NUMBER)
  2  PARTITION BY RANGE (ID)
  3     (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1),
  4      PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));

Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO part_table VALUES (0);

1 row inserted

SQL> UPDATE part_table SET ID = 2;

UPDATE part_table SET ID = 2

ORA-14402: updating partition key column would cause a partition change
```

When you allow row movement, you can move rows with an update:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE part_table ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

Table altered

SQL> UPDATE part_table SET ID = 2;

1 row updated
```

This feature doesn't affect performance in most cases: the rows are stored and queried in exactly the same manner whether the feature is enabled or not. However, when row movement is enabled, the rows can be physically moved (similar to delete+insert) with [`ALTER TABLE SHRINK SPACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2192484) for example. **This** may in turn affect index cluster factor for instance, which may affect the performance of some queries.

Row movement is disabled by default because it implies that the `rowid` of a row may change, which is not the usual behaviour in Oracle.

Comment: Enabling row movement also facilitates running alter table shrink space, which in some cases can allow the size of a table to be reduced without a rebuild.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! So even if we enable it queries are still going to take same time. I was expecting some performance improvements.

Comment: Row movement can affects performance. Index queries may need lots of additional I/O operations. You can also read that here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_enable_row_movement.htm

Comment: @ora-600 yes, the rows may be physically moved, it may impact a particularly-well-clustered-index read. However, the schema used in the article to illustrate this point is misleading: it compares a 40 row length table on a 16k datablock database to a 404 row length table on a 4k block database. There is no reason for `enable row movement` to modify the average row length of a table. It won't affect block size either. So the "total reads" is entirely misleading. IMO this site is well-known because it ranks well with search engines, not because of the quality of its content.

Comment: Agreeing with Vincent -- and it is not enabling row movement that would cause any performance issue, as that is merely setting some metadata on the table. Row movement itself may have some negative effect but you either have a valid reason for doing so (allowing rows to move between partitions or a shrink peace to occur) or not, and any downside is just something to be aware of.

Comment: Row movement is also needed for FLASHBACK operations which rewind a table to an earlier state.

Answer (score 5):

Also see http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_callan_oracle_row_movement.htm

ROW MOVEMENT is necessary for following operations:

- Move Rows between Partitions (Partitioned Tables)
- Flashback of tables
- Shrink Tables (Compact, cascade, normal)

Answer to your Question: no performance increase if you enable row movement, but you can shrink tables which would increase your performance for full table queries.

ASKTOM also gives a very good answer to your question:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:35203106066718

Regarding Shrink (which requires ROW MOVEMENT):

> I would suggest benchmarking -- collect performance metrics about the
>   table before and after performing the operation. You would expect full
>   scans to operate more efficiently after, you would expect index range
>   scans to either be unchanged or "better" as you have more rows per
>   block packed together (less data spread). You would be looking for
>   that to happen -- statspack or the tools available in dbconsole would
>   be useful for measuring that (the amount of work performed by your
>   queries over time)

Answer (score 5):

Downside of row movement is that `ROWID`s may be changed. So if you have any queries based on `ROWID` they may return wrong results